# Default Sharepoint 2013 client-side people picker to current user

Tags: javascript, 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin

I'd like to be able to default the client side people picker for SharePoint 2013 to the current (or any) user.

I've read the "How to" MSDN document here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713593.aspx

But I can't find any documentation on the clientpeoplepicker.js file and it's functions.  It's tricky trying to decipher what the events that fire javascript are actually doing.

Thanks,
Ian.

Comment: Ian. I see you were able to set the current user to the people picker. By any chance do you know how to restrict the current user from being displayed in the people picker as in not displaying the current user in the drop down whens earched for him? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This works, but I need to be able to construct the user object from the currently logged on user.  Shouldn't be too difficult I hope !

```
var users = new Array(1);
var user = new Object();
user.AutoFillDisplayText = "Ian Chivers";
user.AutoFillKey = "i:0#.f|membership|ian@kwsservices.onmicrosoft.com";
user.AutoFillSubDisplayText = "";
user.AutoFillTitleText = "ian@kwsservices.onmicrosoft.com\nTenant\nian@kwsservices.onmicrosoft.com";
user.Description = "ian@kwsservices.onmicrosoft.com";
user.DisplayText = "Ian Chivers";
user.DomainText = "kwsservices-7c59c4bf8d655a.sharepoint.com";
user.EntityType = "User";
user.IsResolved = true;
user.Key = "i:0#.f|membership|ian@kwsservices.onmicrosoft.com";
user.LocalSearchTerm = "Ian";
user.ProviderDisplayName = "Tenant";
user.ProviderName = "Tenant";
user.Resolved = true;
users[0] = user;
this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, users, schema);
```